# Correct way of Convert Enhanced Rich Text field to Plain Text (multiline) - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom, column, rich-text, multiline-text-field

I changed a type of a Enhanced Rich Text column to Plain Text field.

[image]

I am seeing similar to the following content in the text field now.

```
<div class="ExternalClass3227FAEFAC38465BADF8165D56926D99"><p>This is used the text 16&#58;50&#160;​</p></div>
```

I wrote C# program (with CSOM) to iterate through each list item and strip the html tags and set just the text. I used regex, to strip html tags as mentioned in [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/180952/sharepoint-csom-convert-enhanced-rich-text-to-plain-text). It does remove the html tags, but it doesnt remove the html characters within the text. I tried, FieldValueAsText and didnt work for me.

I would like to know what the correct way is to achieve this.

Comment: Is there any update ? Did you try the solution in the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another Plain text type column, use the code snippet to get text value from Enhanced rich text column using CSOM then set the Plain Text column with the text value got:

```
        ClientContext oClientContext = new ClientContext("http://sp/sites/MyDev");


        List list = oClientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List5");
        ListItem item = list.GetItemById(1);

        oClientContext.Load(item,a=>a.FieldValuesAsText);
        oClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        item["Test1"]=item.FieldValuesAsText["Test"];
        item.Update();
        oClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot create new columns. There are many applications integrated with this list. So the column has to be the same and I already changed the column type. Then in my c# application I cleaned the html by removing the tags using regex and used html decoding for the remaining text. But I wanted to know if there is a proper way of achieving that.

Comment: If have changed column type to plain text and don't want a new column, then this is the correct way to remove html character by using regex, but there maybe other special character, so regex maybe changed based on the real situation.